# IndexError in python list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to write a python code to encrypt a string.

Encrypts the string and output is an encrypted string.

```
print "Enter the string "
a=raw_input()
b=len(a)+1
i=0
e=''


while i<b:
  c=''
  if i % 3 == 0:
     c+=a[i]
     e+=chr(ord(c)+5)
     del c
  elif i%3==1:
     c+=a[i]
     e+=chr(ord(c)+2)
     del c
  elif i%3==2:
     c+=a[i]
     e+=chr(ord(c)+6)
     del c     
  i=i+1

print e
```

But when on running this script, error comes.

```
c+=a[i]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Here's a hint: give your identifiers *meaningful* names. Even with this short program, it's much more difficult than it should be to follow what is happening to what, and what each thing represents. Please read the [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more tips on improving your coding style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is when `i` becomes equal to `len(a)`, then your `a[i]` will produce **IndexError**.

There can be a lot of other improvements other than this, like you are always executing `c+=a[i]` irrespective of the conditions and many more which you should try to figure out yourself.